# Does right to Data Access request /GDPR supersede restrictions in Employment contract of previous employer

Tags: united-kingdom, gdpr, data-protection

Does right to Data Access request /GDPR supersede restrictions in Employment contract of previous employer ?

Is above fundamental right's affected by
Clauses in temporary employment contract like 'you can not contact client (not to be confused as person but medium sized enterprise-business)'

If one needs to contact client of employer/agency.

Comment: Welcome to law.SE. Could you elaborate a bit more about the details of this case? What would be the nature of the contact? I would expect that the data about a contractor held by the client would fail more into the legal obligations/legitimate interest aspects and not under the "consent" aspect. But in general, law is above contracts unless a specific exception is detailed in the law.

Comment: Agency worker works at Mid-size enterprise (the client) site. Now, she needs to retrieve her data using SAR (or new GDPR request) ~ similar to getting employment data / details of communication. Obiviously, agency has some clauses like- you can not work/ contact the client. So, will this 'Not contact the client' clause would get broken if SAR/GDPR request is made to clients' data protection team?